# Create Play! Framework tag for selenium tests only

Tags: java, selenium, playframework

I'm writing a selenium test using the Play! Framework and some tests have common bits.  I want to pull those common bits out into a Play! tag.  In production code, tags would live under **app/views/tags**.  However, where would a tag live to be only seen by test templates?

I tried putting my tag under **test/tags** and **test/views/tags**, but both ways resulted in the error:

```
The template tags/Login.html or tags/Login.tag does not exist.
```

If I put the tag under **app/views/tags** it works fine.   But obviously this tag is for testing purposes only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags must be under **app/views/tags** (any subfolder of it), otherwise Play won't get them. You canc reate this path: **app/views/tags/testing** and put in there the test-only tags, so developers know not to use them.

To use a tag Demo in that folder use:

```
#{testing.Demo /}
```

If you want to disable them in production (for extra safety) check [this](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.2/play/Play.Mode.html) api. Add to your tag something like:

```
#{if play.mode.isDev()}
     tag code
#{/if}
```

Comment: I tried the if-statement but it comes back with the error: Exception raised was MissingMethodException : No signature of method: static play.Play$Mode.isDev() is applicable for argument types: (). I changed it to #{if play.mode.name() == 'DEV'} which works.  I like your solution better as it is cleaner but any ideas why it gives the error?

Comment: mmm play is a "default" object in the templates, if your modification works use it. I just noticed isDev() is not static (my bad!) so probably it should be something like #{if play.mode.isDev()} instead

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Tags must be under app/views/tags or any subfolder. How ever I'm sure you can define Tags in a module and import this only in test mode. A little bit complicated  but clean.